# How to Echo delete link into php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, echo

I need to delete a row but I can't do it. Tell me please, how can this be done?

```
$id=0;
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
{
$id++;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$id}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row["BTITLE"]}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row["KEYWORDS"]}</td>";
echo "<td><a href='{$row["FILE"]}' 
target='_blank'>View</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='view_books.php?id={$id}'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I added

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "database.php";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["AID"]))
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $delete=mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `book` WHERE `BID`='$id'");
        header("location:alogin.php");
        die();
    }
?>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `delete.php` that accept as parameter an `id` to delete. Then delete the row from table that corresponds to that `id`. I assume you can do it, if not, take some hints from file `$row["FILE"]`.

Now your loop should look like:

```
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
{
  $i++;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>{$i}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$row["BTITLE"]}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$row["KEYWORDS"]}</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='{$row["FILE"]}' target='_blank'>View</a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id={$i}'>Delete</a></td>";
  // OR, better if you know what it means:
  echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id={$row["id"]}'>Delete</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: add your delete file to your question so we can see the code more clearly and see if there is a mistake there.

Comment: Already I can tell it's not $_POST but rather $_GET (in this case). and run the `id` of the `$row` not `$i` of the loop, they are not the same